# Scroll Pagination returns wrong case

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am using `laravel 10`.

I am having the following controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Prompt;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;


class PromptController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     * if the link is like primaprompt.com/ then the default type is 'new'
     */
    public function index(Request $request, $type = 'new')
    {
        $perPage = 60;
        $search = $request->get('search');
        
        // Modify the cache key to include both the type and the search
        $cacheKey = 'prompts-' . $type . '-' . $search;
        
        $prompts = Cache::remember($cacheKey, 60, function () use ($search, $perPage, $type) {
            $query = Prompt::query();
        
            if ($type) {
                // Set the date for the last 96 hours, for the last 4 days
                $date = Carbon::now()->subHours(96);
        
                switch ($type) {
                    case 'hot':
                        $query->where('created_at', '>=', $date)
                              ->orderBy(DB::raw('views'), 'desc');
                        break;
                    case 'top':
                        $query->where('created_at', '>=', $date)
                              ->orderBy(DB::raw('views + upvotes'), 'desc');
                        break;
                    case 'new':
                        $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
                        break;
                    default:
                        // Query for categories
                        $query->whereJsonContains('categories', $type);
                }
            }
        
            // search if a string exists
            if (!empty(trim($search))) {
                $query->whereFullText('prompt', $search);
            }
        
            $query->where('deleted', 0)
                  ->whereNotNull('prompt')
                  ->where('prompt', '!=', '');
        
            $this->logSQLQuery($type, $query, $search);
        
            // Use a custom paginate function
            return $query->paginate($perPage);
        });
        
        $randomImageUrl = $this->getRandomImage();
        
        return view('index', compact('prompts', 'randomImageUrl'));
    }
    
    public function paginated(Request $request, $type = 'new')
    {
        $perPage = 60;
        $search = $request->get('search');
    
        $query = Prompt::query();
    
        if ($type) {
            // Set the date for the last 96 hours, for the last 4 days
            $date = Carbon::now()->subHours(96);
    
            switch ($type) {
                case 'hot':
                    $query->where('created_at', '>=', $date)
                          ->orderBy(DB::raw('views'), 'desc');
                    break;
                case 'top':
                    $query->where('created_at', '>=', $date)
                          ->orderBy(DB::raw('views + upvotes'), 'desc');
                    break;
                case 'new':
                    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
                    break;
                default:
                    // Query for categories
                    $query->whereJsonContains('categories', $type);
            }
        }
    
        // search if a string exists
        if (!empty(trim($search))) {
            $query->whereFullText('prompt', $search);
        }
    
        $query->where('deleted', 0)
              ->whereNotNull('prompt')
              ->where('prompt', '!=', '');
    
        // Use a custom paginate function
        $prompts = $query->paginate($perPage);
    
        // Make sure the pagination links include the type and the search query
        $prompts->appends(['search' => $search, 'type' => $type]);
    
        return view('partials.prompts', compact('prompts'));
    }
```

In my view I am using this javascript to load images:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/4.2.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Add a script to handle infinite scrolling -->
    <script>
        const loadMorePlaceholder = document.querySelector('#load-more-placeholder');
        let currentPage = {{ $prompts->currentPage() }};
        let lastPage = {{ $prompts->lastPage() }};
        let isLoading = false;

        const searchForm = document.querySelector('.search-box');
        const searchButton = document.querySelector('#search-button');
        const loadingSpinner = document.querySelector('#loading-spinner');

        searchForm.addEventListener('submit', () => {
            document.querySelector('#search-button-text').style.display = "none"; // hide the button text
            document.querySelector('#loading-spinner').style.display = 'inline-block'; // show the spinner
        });

        function loadMoreImages() {
            if (isLoading || currentPage >= lastPage) return;
            isLoading = true;
            currentPage++;

            const search = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('search');
            const searchParam = search ? `&search=${encodeURIComponent(search)}` : '';

            fetch(`/prompts?page=${currentPage}${searchParam}`)
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(html => {
                    document.querySelector('#image-container').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
                    isLoading = false;
                    document.querySelector('#loading-spinner').style.display = 'none'; // hide the spinner
                    document.querySelector('#search-button-text').style.display = 'inline'; // show the button text
                });
        }

        function onScroll() {
            const rect = loadMorePlaceholder.getBoundingClientRect();
            if (rect.top <= window.innerHeight) {
                loadMoreImages();
            }
        }

        window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    </script>
```

These are my `web.php` routes:

```
// For pagination
Route::get('/prompts', [PromptController::class, 'paginated']);

// to load for a certain type like `new` or `hot` everything:
// display hot, top, new and category prompts
Route::get('/{type?}', [PromptController::class, 'index']);
```

My challenge is that when I am doing a query for the category like `/house` the first 60 images are returned correctly, but then the next 60 images are from the `new`-case and I only get further images from the `new- case` when scrolling down. So basically my `paginated function` does not know about the queried category.

Furthermore, my code in my index function and my paginated function is mostly redundant.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: /house, triggers the index method of your controller so it doesn't have anything to do with the paginated method. So why do you say your paginated method does not work?

Comment: @MohammadhosseinFereydouni When I scroll the javascript triggers the paginated method and loads the wrong images.